# Convert DateTime object java to Json string

Tags: android, json

I want to convert date time object in java to json string in format as below:

```
{"date":"/Date(18000000+0000)/"}
```

I did like this but it didn't give me the format i desired:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.put("date",new Date());
```

and the result of object.toString()

```
{"date":"Fri May 04 11:22:32 GMT+07:00 2012"}
```

i want the string "Fri May 04 11:22:32 GMT+07:00 2012" transform to "/Date(18000000+0000)/" (18000000+0000 here is just a example).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Probably repost [SimpleDateFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056703/simpledateformat)

Comment: i'm using json in android with library org.json.JSONObject

Comment: @Crazenezz can you give me more detail for my case. i want to format datetime in format "18000000+0000"?

Comment: What are the two portions in your date string?  (ie what is 18000000 and what is +0000 ? )

Comment: actually i see the string {"date":"/Date(18000000+0000)/"} is generated from iphone app. i dont know what format for 18000000+0000 is. but i need to generate the same string as iphone app when i get datetime obj in java.

Comment: What "source" date converts to 18000000+0000?

Comment: i dont know, i just want to ask everyone that if i get a datetime obj in java, then how can i convert this obj into format string like this "/Date(18000000+0000)/"

Comment: You don't know what the format is - and you don't know the information needed to try and *derive* what the parts are.  How can we help?

Comment: @MichaelP: Can you elaborate what format for "18000000+0000"?

Comment: @MichaelP: Format I mean, is it "DDmmYYYY+HHMM"?

Comment: i just dont know what format  "18000000+0000" means, and i want to ask everyone about this format, that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date format that you want is `/Date(<epoch time><Time Zone>)/`.
You can get the epoch time in java using `long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;`(found at [this link](http://www.epochconverter.com/)) and the time zone you can get by using the date and time patteren as `Z`. Then combine all the strings into one and store it to the Json Object.
Other possibility is that the time you are getting from iOS device may be of the pattern `yyMMddHHmmssZ` as got from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Check the output on the iOS device at different times and identify the correct pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution, although it is not a good way, but I finally find a workable solution.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("Z");
Date date = new Date();
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.put("date", "/Date(" + String.valueOf(date.getTime()) + format.format(date) + ")/");
```

Comment: "18000000+0000" means that Unix timestamp + timezone

Comment: This is my solution too...worked with .net WCF web service. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static String convertToJsonDateTime(String javaDate)

  {
     SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date currentDate = null;
        try {
            currentDate = dateFormat.parse(javaDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long time =currentDate.getTime();
    return  "\\/Date("+time+"+0000)\\/";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution : I think this is the simplest Way

```
DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
yourJsonObject.accumulate("yourDateVarible",dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

From [json.org](http://json.org/java/)'s description of `JSONObject`:

> The values can be any of these types: Boolean, JSONArray, JSONObject, Number, and String, or the JSONObject.NULL object.

This library doesn't support the "complex" mapping of a Date to a JSON representation.  You'll have to do it yourself.  You may find something like [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If your format like this -> "DDmmYYYY+HHMM"

1. DD -> Day (2 Digit)
2. mm -> Month (2 Digit)
3. YYYY -> Year (4 Digit)
4. HH -> Hour
5. MM -> Minute

Than you can do like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("DDmmYYYY+HHMM");
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.put("date", "/Date(" + format.format(new Date()) + ")/");
```

Comment: that's great, but i not sure  "18000000+0000" equivalent to format "DDmmYYYY+HHMM". ok i will research more about this format.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that's a representation of `ISO international date-time` format.

> YYYYMMDD+HHMM

I think now you will be able to create that string

may be like,

`Date d=new Date();
String tmp="";
tmp="/Date("d.getYear()+""+d.getMonth()+""+d.getDate()+"+"+d.getHours()+""+d.getMinutes()+")/";`

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade one of the previous answer:

```
 public static String convertToJsonDateTime(Date dateToConvert) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
        long time = dateToConvert.getTime();
        return "/Date(" + time + "+0000)/";
    }
```

Comment: You never use dateFormat after you create it