# How format date in java/android

Tags: java, android, datetime, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I am trying to develop an android application, regarding with that I have got some data from server.

Here I need to convert a date which comes in the given format **"2013-12-31T15:07:38.6875000-05:00"** 
I need to convert this in to a date object or a calendar object how can we do this?

I have tried with code given below. But it doesn't reach my expectation

```
String dateString="2013-12-31T15:07:38.6875000-05:00";
Date date = null;
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");
try {
    date = df.parse(dateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return date;
```

Comment: what is dateString here?

Comment: i just edited my ques??

Comment: FYI, that format is the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Comment: is this still not resolved ?

Answer (score 4):

Your format string doesn't match the date format you are getting. You should use the following format string:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"
```

- `SSS` is for *milliseconds*.
- `X` is for [ISO 8601 timezone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone)

Comment: OK. Can you print the value of `dateString`. What value does it contain? If it is the value you have shown, it should work.

Comment: its same as i mention in the question. 2013-12-31T15:07:38.6875000-05:00

Comment: ohh.. finally its cleared... i have just remove the "z" from the end

Comment: @user1672337 Actually, you need to use `X` instead of `Z`. The timezone is ISO 8601 format.

Comment: @user1672337 Removing `Z` will not give you correct time. You have simply discarded the timezone itself. That's not correct. Use `X` instead of `Z`.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:**

As you are getting `2013-12-31T15:07:38.6875000-05:00` as a date value, you need to define a format to parse the date.

```
String myDateString= "2013-12-31T15:07:38.6875000-05:00";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
try {
    date = df.parse(myDateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Step 2:**
Once you parse the date, you can format it into desired format.

**For example:** Let's convert the parsed `Date` object into the `yyyy-MM-dd` value.

```
SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String strNewDate = newFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: here is some problem , when we convert this date it goes to Tue Dec 31 17:02:13 GMT 2013 some change in time, because i can't use "z" in the end

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following format for your string formatter

"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

Source : [SimpleDateFormat ignoring month when parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056703/simpledateformat)

For reading : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
 String string = "2013-12-31T15:07:38.6875000-05:00";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

[Simple date formats](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you were using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, you could skip the formatter and feed the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string directly to the constructor of a [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTime dateTime_DefaultTimeZone = new DateTime( "2013-12-31T15:07:38.6875000-05:00" );
```

Output to localized time zone and language…

```java
String localizedOutput = DateTimeFormat.forStyle("LS").withLocale(Locale.CANADA_FRENCH).withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ).print( dateTime_DefaultTimeZone );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTime_DefaultTimeZone: " + dateTime_DefaultTimeZone );
System.out.println( "localizedOutput: " + localizedOutput );
```

When run…

```java
dateTime_DefaultTimeZone: 2013-12-31T12:07:38.687-08:00
localizedOutput: 31 décembre 2013 15:07
```