# How to compare time string with current time in java?

Tags: java, datetime, comparison

I have a time string like "15:30" i want to compare that string with the current time.
Please suggest something easy.
And how to get the current time in hour minute format("HH:mm")

Comment: Reference SimpleDateFormat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056703/simpledateformat

Comment: Do you want a range for "now"? eg at "12:34.999", 12:34 is a match, but 1 millisecond later it isn't - is that what you want?

Comment: I just want to compare if the current time is greater than the time string or not.

Comment: This is my time string which i want to compare.
String time1End  = Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":15";
i converted that into below format.
java.util.Date endTime1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(time1End);
now convert sstemdate into the above time format.
java.util.Date systemdate = new java.util.Date();             
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String systemTime = parser.format(systemdate);
java.util.Date currentTime  = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(systemTime);

Then we can compare like that.
if (currentTime.after(endTime1))

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalTime
    .now()
    .isAfter( 
        LocalTime.parse( "15:30" ) 
    )
```

## Details

You should be thinking the other way around: *How to get that string turned into a time value*. You would not attempt math by turning your numbers into strings. So too with date-time values.

Avoid the old bundled classes, java.util.Date and .Calendar as they are notoriously troublesome, flawed both in design and implementation. They are supplanted by the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29). And java.time was inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Both [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) and [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) offer a class to capture a time-of-day without any date to time zone: `LocalTime`.

## java.time

Using the java.time classes built into Java, specifically [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). Get the current time-of-day in your local time zone. Construct a time-of-day per your input string. Compare with the `isBefore`, `isAfter`, or `isEqual` methods.

```
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
LocalTime limit = LocalTime.parse( "15:30" );
Boolean isLate = now.isAfter( limit );
```

Better to specify your desired/expected time zone rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now( z );  // Explicitly specify the desired/expected time zone.
LocalTime limit = LocalTime.parse( "15:30" );
Boolean isLate = now.isAfter( limit );
```

## Joda-Time

The code in this case using the Joda-Time library  happens to be nearly the same as the code seen above for java.time.

Beware that the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
- See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply, i am using java 6, can you provide the same solution for java 6

Comment: @mayanksharma [Joda-Time 2.3](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) works in Java 5, 6, 7, and 8. Simply add [the jar file](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/) to your project.

Comment: @mayanksharma Update: The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migrating to the java.time classes. For Java 6 & 7, you'll find much of the java.time functionality back-ported in the ThreeTen-Backport project. For Android, ThreeTenABP.

Answer (score 9):

Just compare the strings as normal like so:

```
String currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());
String timeToCompare = "15:30";
boolean x = currentTime.equals(timeToCompare);
```

If the times are the same x will be `true` if they are not x will be `false`

Answer (score 3):

Following would get the time. You can than use it to compare

```
String currentTime=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation where I need to compare time string like "15:30" with the current time. 
I am using **Java 7** so I can not use Basil Bourque's solution.
So I have implemented one method which takes one string like "15:30" and 
check with current time and returns **true if current time is after input time**.

```
public static boolean checkSlaMissedOrNot(String sla) throws ParseException {
        boolean slaMissedOrnot = false;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(sla.substring(0, 2)));
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(sla.substring(3)));
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        if (Calendar.getInstance().after(cal)) {
            System.out.println("it's SLA missed");
            slaMissedOrnot = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("it's fine & not SLA missed");
        }
        return slaMissedOrnot;
    }
```

Calendar has other use full methods like `after(Object when)`

> Returns whether this Calendar represents a time after the time represented by the specified Object.
>   You can use this method also to compare time string with the current time.

Answer (score 1):

So my Solution is a little bit different, Its starts with creating an clock with the current time, and testing the hour agaisnt a user defined int.

```
    public void TextClockWindow() {

    this.pack();

    javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, (ActionEvent e) -> {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        String am_pm;
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        int h = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int m = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int s = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        if (calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0) {
            am_pm = "AM";

        } else {
            am_pm = "PM";

        }   // Code to Determine whether the time is AM or PM

        Clock.setText("" + h + ":" + m + " " + am_pm);

        if(h < 5) { //int here which tests agaisnt the hour evwery second
        System.out.println("Success");
        } else {
        System.out.println("Failure"); 
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static String compareTime(String d) {
        if (null == d)
            return "";

        try {

            SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            d = sdf.format(new Date());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return d;

    }
```

then you can compare with your string

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example to compare before and after current time :

MainActivity.java

```
Button search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchBus);
        SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

        String limit = "23:00";
        Date limitBus=null;
        try {
            limitBus = sdfDate.parse(limit);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String start = "07:15";
        Date startBus=null;
        try {
            startBus = sdfDate.parse(start);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String user_time = getCurrentTimeStamp();
        Date now = null;
        try {
            now = sdfDate.parse(user_time);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (now.after(limitBus)||now.before(startBus)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bus Operation Hours : 7:15AM - 11.00PM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            search.setEnabled(false);
        }

        else
        {
            search.setEnabled(true);
        }



//get current time method
 public static String getCurrentTimeStamp() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");//dd/MM/yyyy
        Date now = new Date();
        String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);
        return strDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will check *User Inputted time* with *current system time* and will **return time difference** in long value.

```
public long getTimeDifferenceInMillis (String dateTime) {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        long endTime = 0;

        try {
            //Parsing the user Inputed time ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            endTime = dateFormat.parse(dateTime).getTime(); 
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }

        if (endTime > currentTime)
            return endTime - currentTime;
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

The user should pass the time in **"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"** format.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.