# formatting a date object to a specific format

Tags: java, android

I have the following date

```
Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

At the moment, when i display it in a listview, it has a value of

```
 2014-07-30
```

How can i specify the date object to be in the following format?

```
 2014-07-30 21:30:30.252
```

Is it possible to create a date object that has this format or is it a case of formatting the date object in the view?

thanks in advance

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat javadoc` google

Comment: There is no point in passing `System.currentTimeMillis()` into the `Date` constructor. You get the same thing with just `new Date()`.

Comment: **"At the moment it is has the value of 2014-07-30"** : Huh? How are you getting that date format? A `Date` object created using `System.currentTimeMillis()` has millisecond precision.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleDateFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056703/simpledateformat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
System.out.println(df.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));`

Here's the output of that for me:

> 2014-07-30 16:39:23.092

Comment: Thanks, sorry i didn't explain correctly. i need a date object in that format

Comment: Check my answer, for that :)

Comment: A `Date` object can't be in any format. It's just an instant in time, represented as a number. Only a String can be in some format. A `DateFormat` turns a `Date` into a `String`.

Comment: Date objects are just time since the unix epoch @DheerajBhaskar

Comment: @turtleboy from the java api, a Date is: "A thin wrapper around a millisecond value that allows JDBC to identify this as an SQL DATE value. A milliseconds value represents the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT." Date's have no format, you simply format them on output

Answer (score 1):

## Use df.format

you need to use [`df.format(Date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) method to get date in required format

Eg:

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
 String dateStr = df.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

For more patterns, [visit this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

### Here's some explanation

> Is it possible to get Date object with specific format?

No. `Date` doesn't have any format. It represents the number of milliseconds since epoch. You only get the formatted string using `SimpleDateFormat`, which you can get as above.

Comment: it doesn't return a Date object but a String.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). The pattern you're looking for isn't too far off from the examples on that page.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
format.format(now);
```

Comment: Sorry i didn'y explain correctly. I would like a Date object in that format

Comment: You need to parse a Date you get in that format? A Date is an object, and the format makes sense when serializing and deserializing, but I guess I don't understand what you are asking.