# Date format issue in android when locale is arabic

Tags: android, date, calendar, arabic

I have a serious problem here, I am building an app that will work on Arabic devices, and I need to send dates to the server, I am using Android DatePickerDialog to get the date, but the date always sent with Arabic characters, and when i try to display it again it gives me Unparsable date exception

I have tried the following solutions but no results

- mDateTime = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US).getTime();
- mDateFormater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

but non of them worked for me

any help please.

My date picker dialog code is like following

```
    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private TextView mUserView;
    private Date mAffectedDate;
    private SimpleDateFormat mDateFormater;
    private Date mInitialDate;

    public TextView getUserView() {
        return mUserView;
    }

    public void setUserView(TextView userView) {
        this.mUserView = userView;
    }

    public Date getAffectedDate() {
        return mAffectedDate;
    }

    public void setAffectedDate(Date mAffectedDate) {
        this.mAffectedDate = mAffectedDate;
    }

    public SimpleDateFormat getDateFormater() {
        return mDateFormater;
    }

    public void setDateFormater(SimpleDateFormat mDateFormater) {
        this.mDateFormater = mDateFormater;
    }

    public Date getInitialDate() {
        return mInitialDate;
    }


    public void setInitialDate(Date mInitialDate) {
        this.mInitialDate = mInitialDate;
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
        c.setTime(mInitialDate);
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        Date date = new Date();
        date.setYear(year - 1900);
        date.setMonth(month);
        date.setDate(day);

        mAffectedDate.setYear(year - 1900);
        mAffectedDate.setMonth(month);
        mAffectedDate.setDate(day);
        mUserView.setText(mDateFormater.format(date));
    }
}
```

Comment: Post more of your code it is not possible to debug with so little info.

Comment: Can you set the time in milliseconds? if yes then use this function over here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27023189/3879470 to get date as string. And use `SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy", Locale.US);`

Comment: Problem may be in arabic formatted dates to server. You can send the time to server in milliseconds instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
Calendar.set(int year, int month, int day, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second)
```

Sets the year, month, day of the month, hour of day, minute, and second fields. Other fields are not 
    changed; call clear first if this is not desired. The month value is 0-based, so it may be clearer to use a constant like JANUARY.
Like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
 public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
  cal.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
  // get time in milliseconds
  Long timeInmilliseconds = cal.getTimeInMillis();
  // print time
  Log.v("log", "Date "+ new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
 }
```

Also see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html):

A common mistake is to implicitly use the default locale when producing output meant to be machine-readable. This tends to work on the developers test devices (especially because so many developers use en_US), but fails when run on a device whose user is in a more complex locale. 
For example, if you are formatting integers some locales will use non-ASCII decimal digits. As another example, if you are formatting floating-point numbers some locales will use ',' as the decimal point and '.' for digit grouping. That is correct for human-readable output, but likely to cause problems if presented to another computer (parseDouble(String) cannnot parse such a number, for example).

Comment: Wouldn't this be wrong in any country other than US?