# string to sql date conversion in java

Tags: java, string, date, simpledateformat

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");    
String stringdate = "Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 CST 2014";
Date stringFromDate = null;
try {
  Date dtt= formatter.parse(stringDate);
  System.out.println(dtt);
} 
catch (ParseException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am receiving an exception `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 CST 2014"` tried so many times but it is not working.

Here i have "stringdate " as fixed format and i have to display in MM/DD/yyyy format. That's my requirement.

Comment: The format of your date doesn't match with the format used in the `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: unable to find the match can you please help on that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "unable to find the match" - have you read the documentation for `SimpleDateFormat`? Compare your pattern with the value you're parsing...

Comment: Read the [API documentation of `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (<= click the link), it explains exactly what the pattern means.

Comment: If you check your current format, you're using MM/dd/yyy which means 2 digits for month, followed by `/`, followed by two digits for day, followed by `/`, followed by 4 digits for year, and you're sending `"Wed Jan 01"` (apart from the rest of the format and from your String). How do you expect a match?

Comment: i found the patter to be "EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy"

Comment: But i am expecting the date to be in "MM/DD/yyyy"

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleDateFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056703/simpledateformat)

Comment: @tom What exactly do you mean? `Date` objects do not have a format. It's not possible to have a `Date` object in a certain format. A `Date` object is just a date value, it doesn't have a format by itself.

Comment: You probably mean `MM/dd/yyyy` instead of `MM/DD/yyyy` since this would result in an interesting output. `D`  stands for *Day in Year*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you are using for your [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat()) is wrong.

This pattern should match your given date format:

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy
```

Use it when you create your `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
```

For more info on what the different letters mean, have a look at the [documentation for `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat()).

Note also that `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` **won't give you a `java.sql.Date`** as mentioned in the title, but rather a `java.util.Date`.

**Edit:** To **output the date in a different format**, you would create a second `SimpleDateFormat` with the pattern that represents the desired output format. Then you can convert it back to the String you want using `SimpleDateFormat.format()`:

```
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String output = outputFormat.format(yourDate);

System.out.println(output);
```

**All in all**, this results in the following code:

```
String input = "Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 CST 2014";
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");

try {
    Date date = inputFormat.parse(input);

    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String output = outputFormat.format(date);

    System.out.println(output); // 01/01/2014

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Its the other way, I have the String format of date fixed. I want to change it to MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: So, you have a fixed pattern you create your `SimpleDateFormat` with and you can create your `stringdate` the way you want? Or the other way round?

Comment: exactly, i want to display the date to be in MM/DD/YYYY format

Answer (score 1):

To get Date in MM/dd/yyyy try using second SimpleDateFormat as:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: Its the other way, I have the String format of date fixed. I want to change it to MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: Please update your post with this info and output that you expect.

Comment: i did it, Please check