# How to format a date with specific format with the same Date Data?

Tags: java

Could any one help me on below code, When i try to execute the below code.
 i am getting the below as a output, Please Correct me to convert same Date. with below format.

### current output:

Tue Jan 23 00:05:00 IST 2018

### Expected Output:

Tue May 23 00:05:00 IST 2018

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String format = "yyyy-mm-dd";
        String date = "2018-05-23";
        Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(date);
        System.out.println(date2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Common problem: `MM` not `mm`. Please [links to similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=simpledateformat+not+working+for+month+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Use `yyyy-MM-dd`. `mm` is for minutes

Comment: Thanks alot Ernest Kiwele. It's working Fine.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Which BTW will parse your date string without any explicit formatter.