# How can I retrieve date from database and convert to Calendar?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, java-calendar

I am doing code in Eclipse using Java Swing and MySQL. I am storing Date of birth using Calendar in database.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String DOB=sdf.format(db1.getDate());
```

I want to retrieve date from database and display in GUI for updating if user want to update.

How can I do that?

```
String idpop = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null , "Enter Student ID to update record:");
int sid=Integer.parseInt(idpop);

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schl","root","root");

String sql = "select * from stud_info where ID='"+sid+"' ";
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                      
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
if(rs.next()) {
                            
                String Sid=rs.getString("ID");
                id1.setText(Sid);
                String Snm=rs.getString("Name");
                nm1.setText(Snm);
                                       
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
                java.util.Date date = sdf.parse("DOB");
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(date);
                db1.setCalendar(calender);         
                                   
                String Sem=rs.getString("Email");
                em1.setText(Sem);
                String Smb=rs.getString("MobNo");
                mb1.setText(Smb);
                String Saddr=rs.getString("Address");
                addr1.setText(Saddr);
                String Sssc=rs.getString("SSCMrks");
                ssc1.setText(Sssc);
                String Shsc=rs.getString("HSCMrks");
                hsc1.setText(Shsc);        
                       }
```

In that, I am trying for updating records, and for that, I am taking id from a user by pop-up and then It is loading data from the database but for dob, it giving error for parsing. So I want to know how to convert the date to Calendar??  I have removed the code of date after that it gave the current date and other data loading normally.

Comment: For the last question, you could always read the documentation, https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: *"One more question"* You're welcome to ask many questions on SO, so long as they are well researched and adequately expressed, but for the site to work best, each question should be asked on a separate question thread. Please [edit] this question to remove the 2nd one, and start a new thread about it **if you need to after checking** the [Java Docs for `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#<init>(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Mrunal, what results are you getting now? Is the problem that you aren't getting _any_ data from the DB, that the `DOB` field is not returning what you expect, or that you're getting an error at a specific line? (btw the `'MM'` is a convention for specifying date formats, the doc link above goes into more detail but `MM` -> two-digit number, `MMM` -> short name of month, `MMMM` -> full name)

Comment: All other data I am getting but I have problem with date which i am storing while inserting information. I am used Calendar to store date but when i want to retrive and want to show in again in datechooser. But how ?

Comment: *"All other data I am getting.."* Tip: Add @JimJ (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @MRUNALMUNOT can you tell what's stored in your database? It looks like it might be a string. Are you getting a specific error, like a type error, or is the type conversion (from `String DOB` to `Timestamp Sdb`) doing something unexpected with your data (like returning a blank string, or the wrong date?)

Comment: @JimJ I am edited question and added image. @Abra data type in database is `DATE` only.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the firstr in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2).

Comment: @MRUNALMUNOT - Your code makes your application vulnerable to SQL Injection. Make sure you apply the recommendations from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65396571/10819573).

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work.

```
        LocalDate date = rs.getObject("DOB", LocalDate.class);
```

This gives you an instance of the modern `LocalDate` type, which is much nicer to work with than the old `Calendar` and `Date` classes. At the same time it saves you from any parsing. Edit: Since JDBC 4.2 (out in 2014) the conversion from a date in SQL to a LocalDate is supported (implemented by MySQL for very long now). You’re now ready for the day when either your date picker gets updated to java.time or you pick a more modern date picker. In the meantime, if you need a `Calendar` for the date picker that you are currently using, convert like this:

```
        ZonedDateTime startOfDay = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.from(startOfDay);
```

> One more question. Why MM is capital in
> `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`?

No matter if using the modern `DateTimeFormatter` or the old and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`or a similar formatter in some other language than Java format pattern letters are case sensitive. If both upper case and lower case of a letter can be used, they have different meanings. For example:

- Lower case `yyyy` means year of era while upper case `YYYY` means week-based year (the year that the week number belongs to, not always the same as the calendar year that the date belongs to). Often lower case is for the most used meaning.
- Lower case `mm` is for minute of hour while upper case `MM` is for month of year (think: a month is longer than a minute).
- Lower case `dd` is for day of month (1–31 in the Gregorian calendar) while upper case `DDD` is for day of year (1–366) (think: the day of year number is typically greater and again not so often used).

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- Related question: [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2)
- Example of a date picker that supports java.time: [LGoodDatePicker](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker)
- [Question about the difference between format pattern letters `mm` and `MM`: SimpleDateFormat ignoring month when parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056703/simpledateformat-ignoring-month-when-parsing)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `java.util.Date date = sdf.parse("DOB");` is trying to parse the *String* `"DOB"`, not the value of `DOB` in your database.

`java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(rs.getString("DOB"));` might work instead.

You can also try passing in a dummy date string (like "2020-12-09") to see if that shows up in your GUI, without an exception, and then working to figure out how to get the string from the DB to replace the dummy date string.

Abra's comment does suggest a possible future improvement: most databases have specific date/time/timestamp types you could use instead, which might offer more guarantees than converting to a string, storing a string, and then converting back into a `Date`.

Comment: I am applied code given by you. Now it is not giving error loading all the field except date field is remain blank.

Comment: @MRUNALMUNOT can you tell what is in rs.getString("DOB")? I'm not familiar with all of your code, but if I _was_ working in an unfamiliar codebase, the next steps I'd take would be (a) making sure that if I pass a fixed, dummy string to `sdf.parse()` (like `sdf.parse("2020-01-01")`) it shows up in the calendar field and (b) putting the `String` value of `rs.getString("DOB")` somewhere _without_ a type conversion, so I can see what is being passed to `sdf.parse()`. Like, assign the value of `rs.getString("DOB")` to the textarea on your form, or logging it to the console.

Comment: DOB-date of birth of student. Which stored using that Calendar in java swing in database. `sdf.parse("2020-01-01")` I am tried it but it is showing other date irrelated with it.

Comment: another date like 10-jun-1 something

Comment: @MRUNALMUNOT I assume the problem is that `sdf.parse()` is expecting a particular date format by default (like "01-01-2020", for example) but the string you're passing in doesn't match that format. What _exact_ string are you passing to `sdf.parse()` that is displaying `10-jun-1`?

Comment: I am passing string like "2000-12-09".

Answer (score 1):

### Your code makes your application vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Forget about date operations for a moment and focus on your JDBC code. The way you have passed the value of `sid` in your query, is a classic example of how SQL Injection works. You should use `?` as the placeholder for parameters and pass the parameters using setter methods. That will also help you get rid of the single quotes that you have used explicitly. Learn more about using `PreparedStatement` from [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Also, make a habit of using [the try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) when you are dealing with some resource (e.g. DB connection, I/O stream etc).

Your code should be as follows:

```
String idpop = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame , "Enter Student ID to update record:");
int sid = Integer.parseInt(idpop);

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schl","root","root");

String sql = "SELECT * FROM stud_info WHERE id =?";

try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {

    ps.setString(1, sid); 
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    //...
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The existing answers have already provided you with the fix related to date operations. I have added a couple of more helpful links regarding your following question:

> One more question. Why MM is capital in
> `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`?

`SimpleDateFormat` evaluates `M` as **Month in year** while `m` as **Minute in hour**. Check the [documentation of `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to learn more about various symbols related to date, time, timezone, timezone offset etc.

This is true even for the parsing/formatting API, [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for the modern date-time types.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html), the DATE data type maps to class `java.sql.Date`. So you should use method [getDate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate(java.lang.String)), in interface `java.sql.ResultSet` to retrieve the value of column DOB.

```java
java.sql.Date dob = rs.getDate("DOB");
```

I'm guessing that `db1` (in the code in your question) is a [JDateChooser](https://toedter.com/jcalendar/), so all you need to do is call method [setDate](http://javadox.com/com.toedter/jcalendar/1.4/doc/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser.html#setDate(java.util.Date))

```java
db1.setDate(dob);
```

et voilà

Comment: Mrunal Munot, if Abra’s guess is correct, you may want to look for a newer date picker component, one that supports java.time, the modern Java date and time API. JDateChooser is really old. I haven’t got experience with any myself. What I have seen of [LGoodDatePicker](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker) looks good to me, for example. Search for others.